# set textview in a specific area of frame

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I have a message program that add a message in to text view inside a scroll view.

I have one frame for display the message.my problem is text of text view is appear on frame not inside a specific area of frame, is their any way to do this.

My xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_all"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="15" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:background="@drawable/love_sms_frame"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDetails"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In auctor varius ligula quis imperdiet. Cras at arcu eget ligula lacinia aliquam. Donec ultricies neque eu nisl elementum sed luctus leo porta. Nunc gravida molestie sodales. Nam sit amet lacus a odio dictum dignissim. Pellentesque nec tincidunt urna." />
            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ibPrev"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/love_sticker_previous_button"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ibShare"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/love_sticker_share_button" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ibNext"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/love_sticker_next_button"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: please post some screen shot of this.

Comment: I have no enough reputation for post screen shot.

Comment: You can upload your image in a server, and give us the link. Otherwise explain more what you have and what you expect. We don't have your backgrounds xml files so we don't know where is the transparent area and where is the colored area.

Comment: here link of screenshot     http://imageshack.com/a/img673/6628/hTfYig.jpg

Comment: Try to add *android:padding="25dp"* to your TextView (txtDetails)

Comment: I try this but it works on one device perfect.when try to run this code on some larger device than the text is appear on frame.

Comment: Yeah, because in larger device the image stretched and the distance between the pink rectangle and the transparent area increase. Maybe you should use differents values of padding depends on device size (values, values-large, values-xlarge...)

Comment: There are 2 ways to do this.1. Customize your textview.
2. add a drawable border to the textview

Comment: @Rami how to it is possible. can you give me some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1: add the values of the padding depends on screen size (e.g):

- in `res/values/dimens.xml`

  < dimen name="sms_padding">25dp < /dimen>
- in `res/values-large/dimens.xml`

  < dimen name="sms_padding">35dp < /dimen>
- in `res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml`

  < dimen name="sms_padding">50dp < /dimen>

.....

step 2: add the padding to you TextView:

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtDetails"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In auctor varius ligula quis imperdiet. Cras at arcu eget ligula lacinia aliquam. Donec ultricies neque eu nisl elementum sed luctus leo porta. Nunc gravida molestie sodales. Nam sit amet lacus a odio dictum dignissim. Pellentesque nec tincidunt urna."
         android:padding="@dimen/sms_padding" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) image as the background of the textview. That way you can specify where the image will be stretched (ideally in the center) and where the text will be placed. See link for details.

*Edit*

So, just use the file from [here](http://tekeye.biz/2012/android-9patch-files) which you seem to be using anyway, it in [this](http://tekeye.biz/download/ninepatch.zip) file in \res\drawable\heartsframe.9.png

Replace `android:background="@drawable/love_sms_frame"` with `android:background="@drawable/heartsframe"` in your LinearLayout and it should work ok.